# Looking to create a scheduling web app

Tags: web-development

I'd like advice on creating a web based application for my work. I'll describe the problem to solve, our current solution, and some of my ideas for the future. Would be looking for suggestions as to the best language to create this in, as well as some ideas about how to get started.

I work in a scheduling office, which has about 40 employees working on a specific day. We each cover different regions around Canada and the United States. Our office is open 24 hours a day, so while one employee may cover a single region if working during the day (say 8AM-4PM), a single employee may cover 8-10 during the evening or overnight shift. We also have 2 shared tasks that each person covers for an hour or two during the day. We need to make sure at least one person is always covering each of these tasks.

Our current solution is a shared google sheets file. It is manually created day to day by one of our managers and adjusted as necessary throughout the day if a specific region needs more support.

I'd like to create a web based application that can be used to assign employees to different regions and to the 2 shared tasks. It would have to be easily accessible to all other employees working as they may answer calls that need to be transferred to whoever is working a specific region.

Some key requirements:

Automation - I would like it to automatically construct a skeleton schedule of everyone working on a specific day. Our other scheduling software that tracks everyone who is in on a specific day can output an excel file of this, so if this app could pull from this excel file that would be great.
Also if we could associate different employees with different regions this would be awesome. Some people (probably 40% of employees) always work for the same region so should be automatically assigned to that region, while some change around day to day and would require some manual adjustment.

Clarity - Clearly shows who is working a specific location and the coverage for that location during the day

Failsafe - Shows an error if one region or one shared tasks lacks coverage for any period of time

Let me know if you have any advice.